# Проверка имени и фамили

Tags: php

Добрый день!
Как мне добавить буквы украинские и цифри.

Вот код

```
//* Проверка имени *//

        if(isset($user_name)){
            if(strlen($user_name) >= 2){
                if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я-Є-Їa-zа-я]+$/iu", $user_name))
                    $errors = 3;
            } else
                $errors = 2;
        } else
            $errors = 1;
```

// *Проверка фамилии* //

```
        if(isset($user_lastname)){
            if(strlen($user_lastname) >= 2){
                if(!preg_match("/[Є-Їa-zа-я-Є-Їa-zа-я]+/iu", $user_lastname))
                    $errors_lastname = 3;
            } else
                $errors_lastname = 2;
        } else
            $errors_lastname = 1;

        $row2 = $db->super_query("SELECT verification FROM `".PREFIX."_users_param` WHERE user_id = '{$user_id}'");

        if(!$errors AND !$row2['verification']){
            if(!$errors_lastname){
                $user_name = ucfirst($user_name);
                $user_lastname = ucfirst($user_lastname);

                $db->query("UPDATE `".PREFIX."_users` SET user_name = '{$user_name}', user_lastname = '{$user_lastname}', user_search_pref = '{$user_name} {$user_lastname}' WHERE user_id = '{$user_id}'");

                mozg_clear_cache_file('user_'.$user_id.'/profile_'.$user_id);
                mozg_clear_cache();
            } else
                echo $errors;
        } else
            echo $errors;

        die();
    break;
```

Comment: цифры `\d`

Comment: Всмысле?  )

Comment: `/^[\w\d]+$/iu` должно сработать.

Comment: Вам только украинские буквы? Английских и остальных быть не должно? Тогда \w не пойдет. К тому же \w уже содержит цифры и знак подчеркивания (он же не нужен?).

Вопрос на засыпку (не по теме) - а зачем вы обращаетесь к базе, когда у вас была ошибка в имени или фамилии?

И кто вас научил логику и отображение в одном месте хранить? Избавляйтесь от этой привычки - логика в одном месте, отображение в другом.

И если эта проверка однажды начнет тормозить - попробуйте индекс по (user_id; verification).

Comment: Не работает. Пишет всеравно специально символы

Comment: Если считать, что работа \w вас устроит (т.е. не только украинские, но и знак подчеркивание, и английские и другие буквы), то у вас проблема только в том, что вы ищите хоть одно букву/цифру.

А поскольку вас надо только буквы/цифры, то так и надо писать:

    $text = '_ASD23';
    $pattern = "/^[\w]+$/iu";
    $result = preg_match($pattern, $text);
    var_dump($result);

Знак ^ - требует чтобы строка была в начале, знак $ - чтобы строка была в конце.

Т.е. грубо /^[\w]+$/ расшифровывается как - чтобы строка содержала буквы/цифры, и они располагались от начала строки до ее конца.

Comment: Общие сведения о регулярках можно почитать на [википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Про начало и конец строки там написано, так же как и про \w, \d и т.д.

Comment: Проверять имя и фамилию - дурной тон. Имя или фамилия человека не могут быть неправильными.